# PHP:What if the contructor is defined with __construct and classname in same class?

Tags: php, class, constructor

Yes, this is quite subjective, but this would help understanding the behavior of rendering and prioritizing the practice in class entity formation.

Below is what I am describing in words:

```
class anyclass{

function __construct(){
  //Any Required initialization

}



function anyclass(){
  //Any Required initialization

}


}
```

Below are the questions related to this snippet:

1. Is it executible, if yes, then how?
2. If yes, and if both are considered constructor, which will give the
   final output?

Comment: ["For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a `__construct()` function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class."..."As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. This change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes."](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: Does it means, if the keyword __construct is considered as constructor then classnamed method will be considered as just another method of a class and vice-versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes it is executable.
2. `__construct` always wins in PHP 5.

   ```
   class A
   {
       function __construct()
       {
           echo 1;
       }

       function A()
       {
           echo 2;
       }
   }

   new A(); // prints 1 with PHP 5, prints 2 with PHP 4
   ```

Comment: Does it means, if the keyword __construct is considered as constructor then classnamed method will be considered as just another method of a class and vice-versa?

Comment: Correct. For PHP 5, `__construct` is always the constuctor, `classnamed method` is just a normal method.